# Regular Expressions, Python 3,

Tags: python, regex

I have problems to understand this regular expression in python:

```
re.findall(r'([a-z]+?)\w*', "Ham, spam, and, eggs")
```

I understand that:

- `[a-z]` is a class that includes the all letters from a-z
- `+` says that it can appear at least once
- `?` is it can appear once or never

My output for `([a-z]+?)` is:

```
['a', 'm', 's', 'p', 'a', 'm', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'e', 'g', 'g', 's']
```

Now the problems start:

if I test:

```
re.findall(r'([a-z]+?)\w', "Ham, spam, and, eggs")
```

My output is:

```
['a', 's', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'g']  # Why?
```

and if i test the full expression:

```
re.findall(r'([a-z]+?)\w*', "Ham, spam, and, eggs")
```

my output is:

```
['a', 's', 'a', 'e'] # Why?
```

Can somebody explain this to me, please?

Comment: "Ham" contains more than [a-z]...

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstand the use of `+?` * - this means at least once, **non-greedy**, i.e. as a few additional characters as needed to match. In practice, this is the same as `[a-z]` ("at least once and as few times as possible" is the same as, simply, "once").

The other token in your pattern, `\w`, means any "word character", equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Your first attempt, `([a-z]+?)\w`, captures any single, lower-case letter that is followed by any other word character - hence `['a', 's', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'g']`:

```
"Ham, spam, and, eggs"
# ^.  ^.^.  ^.   ^.^.
```

*(Note: `^` is the captured character, `.` is the non-captured match.)*

Your second attempt, `([a-z]+?)\w*` captures any single, lower-case letter followed by as many other word characters as possible, hence only captures once per word (the first lower-case letter):

```
"Ham, spam, and, eggs"
# ^.  ^...  ^..  ^...
```

In both cases, as you have specified a capture group, `findall` only returns the characters *within that group*. If you remove the capture group parentheses, it will capture the whole match:

```
>>> re.findall(r'[a-z]+?\w*', "Ham, spam, and, eggs")
['am', 'spam', 'and', 'eggs']
```

You can try an interactive demonstration [here](http://regex101.com/#python).

* *You have confused it with `?` on its own, which does mean "zero or one times".*

Comment: Yes, all true. But you may want to clarify why the text matched by the `\w` part of the pattern is not being returned in the result. (i.e. If there are capture groups, Python's `findall()` returns only what was captured, otherwise, if there are no capture groups, it returns each whole match.)

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a stab although I am not sure if I am correct.

Does the "?" apply non-greedy 1 or more matching (+ sign) maybe?

So you do not match the "H" in Ham because it is upper case.
Next you we look at "a". Since its followed by a word character (\w) the matching captures the letter "a" there, and carries on to the "," where we start over.

Next letter it matches the s in spam and a following word characters captures the "s" and moves on to th next ",", and so on.